# Extracting pixel value of sentinel 2 data

Tags: r, extract, pixel, qgis, sentinel

Hope everyone in good health. My assignment is regarding the image process and the problem is as follows. I have to extract the pixel values of sentinel data for my study area. The image data I have download is bigger in size. So how can I extract the pixel values for my study area from the bigger image data? I am using R programming and QGIS. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank You

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info? Is the pixel data in raster format, e.g. geoTIFF or ncdf? As a first stop you might want to have a look at 'raster' and 'terra' packages

Comment: The image data is in JPEG2000 format.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide any code / reproducable example, the answer has to be quite general.
For what you want to do, you can use the 'raster' package in R. It depends on gdal, thus you can use all formats specified under [the gdal raster drivers](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html) to easily read in the data.
Once the data is read in, you need to extract values of your study area, using the 'extract' functinon of the raster package.

The code should look something like this:

```
library(raster)

#read in raster
raster("/path/to/file.jpg") -> raster_file

#create extent in size of study area for extracting of data
extent(XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, YMAX) -> study_area_extent

#extract values
extract(raster_file, study_area_extent)
```

For high-resource applications, you might consider the 'terra' package over the 'raster' package.

Comment: thank you. i got the hints to do it.  Now I am facing a different problems. If you could follow this link you can understand my problem.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137216/how-to-change-the-extent-of-raster-file-in-r-from-decimal-degree-to-meter