# How to change the extent of raster file in r from decimal degree to meter?

Tags: r, crop, raster, extent

I have an image data whose reference is in WGS84 UTM ZONE 45N. So the unit extent of this file is in meter. I want to crop a polygon whose reference is in WGS84 UTM ZONE 45N and the extent unit is in decimal degree. I can not crop the polygon because of two different extent units. So how can I change the polygon extent to meters?

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is not possible. You cannot have a the `WGS84 UTM ZONE 45N` coordinate reference system (CRS) with degrees as unit. UTM is a planar CRS and the units are meter (sometimes other units are used, but they cannot be degrees). Also, you cannot simply change the extent from one unit to another. If the CRS of two datasets do not match you can transform one to the CRS of the other. In the case of vector and raster data you should normally transform the vector data. You can read about that [here](https://rspatial.org/terra/spatial/6-crs.html) and in many other places.

But in your case, there is mistake earlier on that you need to fix.